# manual set the properties of connection manager by c3p0

Tags: c3p0

I get a connection from c3p0 pool for batch insert and i set the autoCommit=false,after using,i put it back to the poll. If the autoCommit=false still valid for this connection?

Answer (score 0):

No. According the the JDBC spec, new Connections are autocommit=true, and c3p0 implements transparent Connection pooling, meaning an application that functions correctly in a c3p0 application should also function correctly using an unpooled Connection source.

If you wish, you can override this behavior by defining a ConnectionCustomizer. Something like...

```
package mypkg;

import com.mchange.v2.c3p0.AbstractConnectionCustomizer;
import java.sql.Connection;

public class AutocommitConnectionCustomizer extends AbstractConnectionCustomizer {
    @Override
    public void onCheckOut(Connection c, String parentDataSourceIdentityToken) throws Exception {
        c.setAutoCommit( false );
    }
}
```

Then, in your config...

```
c3p0.connectionCustomizerClassName=mypkg.AutocommitConnectionCustomizer
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: First,thank you very much.As you say,c3p0 override the Connection's close method,in that method,it reset the properties to default,also reset the autoCommit=true. All i want to do it's to ensure that autoCommit to be true after i execute the batch insert. In case it affect other behavior  of mybatis ! Thank you so so much!

Comment: once you set `autoCommit` to `false`, it will remain false regardless of any database operations you perform, until you `close()` the `Connection` or explicitly reset `autoCommit` to `true`.